# Keras custom loss function with multiple output model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, loss-function

In a segmentation task I wanted to have my model to have two outputs because I implemented weight maps as suggested in the original U-net paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf.

As per the suggestion I created weightmaps concentrating some of the ground truth mask to have higher weights. Now I have a model with.

```
weightmap=layers.Lambda(lambda x:x)(weight_map) # A non trainable layer to output this as tensor for loss function
Model=model(inputs=[input,weight_map], outputs=[output,weightmap]
```

Now I need to compute binary cross entropy loss for the following model

```
def custom_loss(target,outputs):
    loss=K.binary_crossentropy(target,outputs[0]) #ouputs[0] should be the model output
    loss=loss*outputs[1] #outputs[1] should be weightmaps 
    return loss
```

This output[0] and output[1] slicing of output tensor from model doesnt work.

Is there anything I can do to implement the following with both outputs of model in a single loss function?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "output tensor from model doesn't work"? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @Srivathsa The loss computation was outside model graph. So, slicing of output tensor doesnt work eventhough my model has two outputs(i.e., The sliced tensor values doesnt correspond to the output and weightmap) and I cannot figure out why. But I made a workaround for introducing these weightmaps by computing the loss inside the model graph. But could not find a solution for this.